# JQuery: Hovering a combo box option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Gday All,

The following code displays a div based on the option that has been selected within a drop down box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SomeDropdown").change(function() {
        var theVal = $("#SomeDropdown option:selected").val();
        $("#SomeDiv_" + theVal).css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

How do I display the div when the user hovers over the value within the  drop down box? (Instead of clicking on it)

Cheers,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can with a standard select box. You can only attach a hover event on the actual drop down as a whole (though you *can* attach it only if a value is selected in it).

If you must have this functionality, you may need to develop your own styled drop down... however this has it's own problems (usability for one).